# Settlement context-meaning help

Tags: meaning-in-context

Settlement refers to a country house

What does coastal settlement mean in this context?

I understand it as a place newly settled, could you confirm my understanding is right?

It's in line fifteen coastal settlement

[image]

Comment: It would be better if you take the effort of typing the whole sentence out, because it is pure English. Someone may down-vote the question because of this or high-rep users may close the question.

Comment: _Settlement_ does _not_ refer to a country house - whatever gave you that idea? It just means a place where people have settled (made their homes). The ones affected by the tsunami were near the coast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **settlement** - a place, typically one which has previously been uninhabited, where people establish a community.

[Source of meaning](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&sxsrf=ALeKk01BuM1D8cvt0quhQOUC2cPyAy67vA%3A1602088821737&ei=de99X-7DLJ2d4-EP_5ePgA4&q=%20settlement%20meaning&oq=%20settlement%20meaning&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzIMCAAQsQMQQxBGEPkBMgIIADICCAAyBggAEAcQHjICCAAyBggAEAcQHjIGCAAQBxAeMgYIABAHEB4yBggAEAcQHjIGCAAQBxAeOgQIABBHUK9uWK9uYMZzaABwA3gAgAHKAYgBygGSAQMyLTGYAQCgAQGqAQdnd3Mtd2l6yAECwAEB&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwiu0vj49aLsAhWdzjgGHf_LA-AQ4dUDCAw&uact=5)

It certainly doesn't refer to country house. And it is not necessary to be a newly settled place. Settlements are typically those which have been existing for quite some now (if not decades already).

According to the above example, settlement means where habitation has developed over years. Hence, ***coastal settlement*** would mean habitation which has developed around the coasts (here Andaman Islands) because of people inhabiting the area and building a livelihood for themselves.

Comment: Re *not [necessarily] a newly settled place*, it's worth noting that the actual example usage from your definition source is ***one of the oldest Viking settlements in western Europe*** - which should be more than enough to clarify that point.

Comment: I mean a settlement means a place just that, the other last part **typically one which has previously....** is optional because says **typically** so is not always. If a settlement in rare cases means a place only, what actually does that mean???? Settlement is synonym of place?? I can use place and settlement interchangeably? I thought uttermost not this is not possible, so what I did is search the meaning of **place** and the least non-sense meaning "tailored" to the context I gave you in the photo is **country house** but I insist does settlement is synonym of place?

Comment: @PabloRamosEscalona: Ordinarily we wouldn't think of "settlement" as simply  meaning "place" (of some particular type). Nor would a *single* house normally be enough to justify the term. It usually refers to *a [small] number of separate **households** living in different **buildings*** (or ***tepees*** or whatever) - and the word "settlement" primarily references those *households* and *inhabitants*, rather than the specific physical location they're living in.

Comment: Alright, I will make my own definition with what you gave me and others, thanks a lot!